# How can I create a logical volume mounted at /opt in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am working on a project and I need to create a logical volume using chef that is mounted at /opt. The problem is that chef seems to install its client to the /opt/chef so the converge fails, but only the first time. The second converge always succeeds. Is there a way to converge in my recipe or to reinstall the client using the recipe?

recipe:

```
lvm_volume_group 'test_group' do
  physical_volumes ['/dev/xvdi']
  wipe_signatures true

  logical_volume 'foo' do
    size '3G'
    filesystem 'xfs'
    mount_point location: '/opt'
  end
end
```

error:
    ===========================================================================
     Error executing action `create` on resource 'lvm_volume_group[test_group]'

```
===========================================================================

 Errno::ENOENT
  -------------
 No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /opt/chef
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kind of can't. You would need to do this setup before installing Chef, so as part of the system initialization or bootstrap. Otherwise you could mount the folder elsewhere, then bindmount only certain subfolders; or mount it elsewhere, copy over `/opt/chef` and then remount to `/opt`. Overall this kind of setup is best handled during machine init.